# Aligning Drop Down List and Input Box in HTML5 and CSS3

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a drop down list where a list is selected and entered into an input box. However the drop down list is not align properly with the input box. I present the codes below.

below is the HTML 5 code

```html
<form class="form" action="put.php" method="post" name="access_form">
<li>
     <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
      <input name="firstname" id="keyword" type="text" placeholder="type first name (required)" required />
     <div id="results">
 <div class="item">abc</div>
 <div class="item">def</div>
 <div class="item">hij</div>
</div>

</li>
</form>
```

below is the css code

```css
.form label {
    width:150px;
    margin-top: 3px;
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
    padding:3px;
}

.form input {
    height:20px; 
    width:220px; 
    padding:5px 8px;
}



#results {
 width: 204px;
        display: none;
 display: absolute;
 border: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
}

#results .item {
 padding: 3px;
 font-family: Helvetica;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
}
```

but anytime i run the code i get the following alignment

[image: the drop down list is out of line with the input box]

Now , how do I align the drop down box and the input box to match each other.

Comment: Can you create a JSFiddle, please?

Comment: Using a `<li>` without a parent `<ul>` seems like bad practice.

Comment: `#results {margin-left:156px;}` - (width of label plus 3px left and 3px right padding) - http://jsfiddle.net/gbtjagme/

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want the input to be on the next line, which would lineup with the list below it:

```
.form label {
    display:block;}
```

or

```
.form input {
    display:block;}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the `<li>` tag belongs in your html, so I've removed it from my answer. If you want to align the results with the input field they should be in the same div. I've simplified here and simply put in your input field inside of the `#results` div. Floating that div to the left will align it's inner content the way I think you want it to.

```css
.form label {
    width:150px;
    margin-top: 3px;
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
    padding:3px;
}

.form input {
    height:20px; 
    width:220px; 
    padding:5px 8px;
}



#results {
    width: 204px;
    border: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
    float: left;
}

#results .item {
 padding: 3px;
 font-family: Helvetica;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
}
```

```html
<form class="form" action="put.php" method="post" name="access_form">
     <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
     <div id="results">
      <input name="firstname" id="keyword" type="text" placeholder="type first name (required)" required />
      <div class="item">abc</div>
      <div class="item">def</div>
      <div class="item">hij</div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Erik, but for a smoother effect I suggest to comment `width` and `border` on `#results` and change `form .item` with `#results .item`

Gianmaria

```css
.form label {
    width:150px;
    margin-top: 3px;
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
    padding:3px;
}

.form input {
    height:20px; 
    width:220px; 
    padding:5px 8px;
}



#results {
    /*width: 204px;*/
    /*border: 1px solid #c0c0c0;*/
    float: left;
}


#results .item {
    padding: 3px;
    font-family: Helvetica;
    border: 1px solid #c0c0c0;
```

```html
<form class="form" action="put.php" method="post" name="access_form">
     <label for="firstname">First Name</label>
     <div id="results">
      <input name="firstname" id="keyword" type="text" placeholder="type first name (required)" required />
      <div class="item">abc</div>
      <div class="item">def</div>
      <div class="item">hij</div>
  </div>
</form>
```